# Col-md-6 caindo para baixo ao invés de ficar do lado

Tags: css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Preciso fazer uma `section` como a da imagem.
[image: Como é para ficar]

Para isso organizei dessa maneira.

**HTML**

```
 <section class="second-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center my-5">
      <div class="col-md-12 box-orange">
          <div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/campos.png" alt="campos"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Texto</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta libero saepe natus nam recusandae molestiae neque reprehenderit quae, impedit eos vero, in eligendi voluptas nostrum deserunt odit voluptatibus voluptate quis?
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.second-section{
.box-orange{
background-image:url('/img/fundo2.png');
height: 400px;
color: white;
img{
  height: 480px;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: -2%;
  }
 }
}
```

Porém o resultado que consegui é esse, com o texto caindo para baixo ao invés de ficar ao lado.
[image: como esta]

Se tratando da responsividade eu preciso deixar assim porém com o col-md-6 dessa maneira ele não fica.

[image: responsividade]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma como vc montou o Grid do Bootstrap está equivocada, vc colocou uma `div col-12` desnecessária, além disso vc usou um `margin-left -2%`, mas `2%` seria mais adequado para o efeito que quer...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
.second-section .box-orange {
    background-image: url('/img/fundo2.png');
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
}

.second-section img {
    height: 480px;
    margin-top: -5%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .second-section .box-orange {
        background-image: url('/img/fundo2.png');
        height: initial;
        color: white;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .second-section img {
        height: 480px;
        margin-top: initial;
        margin-left: initial;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<section class="second-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center my-5 bg-primary">
            
                <div class="col-md-6 box-orange">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ml-5 ml-md-0">
                    <h3>Texto</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta libero saepe natus nam
                        recusandae molestiae neque reprehenderit quae, impedit eos vero, in eligendi voluptas
                        nostrum deserunt odit voluptatibus voluptate quis?
                    </p>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a responsividade para ver se fica melhor de entender.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti dei uma ajustada no código usei o @media no breacking point 768px que é o mesmo que o Bootstrap usa para telas médias `-md-`, mas se vc quiser pode acrescentar outros, eu particularmente acho que não precisa. Para afastar o texto da borda esquerda eu usei a classe `ml-5` que é a maior original do Bootstrap, mas vc pode fazer outra se quiser.